# dealing with Tokens in the session PHP online

Tags: php

I'm making use of storing random token values into session as well as flash message which prints out messages for one time only upon registration of updating profile,, this is working so far like it should on the localhost - wampserver. However, after deploying the website to the live server the process works correctly as long as the user is not logged in, after I log in I just can't update the profile at all, also after a successful registration the message "you have been registered successfully" is shown every time I go to the the homepage while it should only appear once and only once.. and  again on the local server it is working like charm.

So after checking some online resources the answer was it mostly the configuration of php.ini on the server is what causing the problem, so I checked the php.ini on the server and after comparing it to the local one i found these two line missing concerning the Session field:

```
session.save_path = "c:/wamp/tmp"
session.use_only_cookies = 1
```

Then I added them to the online version of php.ini and it still doesn't work, of course I've changed the save_path to some random value but the whole storing in session doesn't work at all until i comment the `session.save_path` line, the other line didn't change anything so I don't know where the problem is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your live server is Unix that save_path will not exist. Try looking at the live server's error logs to see if that gives you some clues as to what is wrong

Comment: It is Linux, and the logs doesn't show anything from today at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this [PHP Based session variable not retaining value. Works on localhost, but not on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475114/php-based-session-variable-not-retaining-value-works-on-localhost-but-not-on-s?rq=1) and it is exactly the cause of the problem, these people using `register_globals` **ON** .. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to write to a directory php doesn't have write access to. when you comment out the line, it stores it in the default php save path, which it does have write permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've already created a tmp folder same level with php.ini with 755 CHMOD but nothing is being stored in it I cleared the session few times and re-logged in but it's the same.

Comment: and you restarted the wamp server everytime?

Comment: it is already working properly on the wamp server, the problem is with the online one

Comment: the online "one". thats vague. do you mean a shared hosting account, your own server or what?

Comment: I mean the one that is not on my machine, not the local server.

Comment: you are being to vague.